# jQuery Validate + JSONP cross domain remote validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate, jsonp

I have a problem using jQuery Validate and cross domain remote validation.
My scenario is:

- PhoneGap mobile app
- PHP scripts on remote server
- jQuery 1.9.1
- jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 as interface framework
- jQuery Validate 1.12.0 as forms validation plugin

In order to interact with server I use jQuery Ajax calls and JSONP as cross domain communication technique.
I have to validate some form fields using remote rules, but because these calls are on another domain (from the app to the server) I have problems with the responses format. Using JSONP I can't return a simple "TRUE" or "FALSE" but a JSONP formatted data.

From server side I have a PHP function that returns a JSON formatted data:

```
if (.....)    
    $return["Result"] = TRUE;    
else
    $return["Result"] = FALSE;

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $jsoncallback . "(" . json_encode(return) . ")";
```

From client side I have this jQuery Validate code:

```
rules: {
    'email': {
        required: true,
        remote: {
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://www.myurl.com/mypage.php',
            data: {
                email: function() {
                    return $('#email').val();
                }
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            success: function(data, status) {
                if (data.Result === false)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
},
messages: {
    'email': {
        required: 'message 1',
        remote: 'message 2'
    }
}
```

The above code seems to work fine when the remote validation is passed, but not when failed.
If I put an alert like this in "success":

```
alert(data.Result);
```

It returns always the correct value, but the code seems to keep going on and it doesn't print the error message.

Is there a way to use jQuery Validate to validate a field using remote rule and JSONP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure `data.Result` is of `boolean` type?

Comment: Hi, if I check the result with `if (data.Result == 'false')` nothing changes...

Comment: please check with `alert(typeof data.Result)`

Comment: The suggested alert returns `boolean`. Behind the alert popup, the code continues running and the form results valid also if the data.Result is FALSE.

Comment: Was this ever solved? I have similar issue where the success method is not called at all and the error is not being shown. Is there any example where JSONP is used for remote? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Validate API](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method) documentation is badly written, but it seems like the PHP page **must** respond with `true` or `false` only, like:

```
echo "false";
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, using JSONP I can't echo "true" or "false", but a json encoded string. This is the cause of the problem :(

Comment: can you create a PHP script on your local server to act as a proxy for the request?

Comment: I can't because client side the code runs on PhoneGap, so I can only use html, css, javascript

Comment: sorry, I meant a proxy script on *remote* server; can't JSONP be removed just for validation?

Comment: Actually I've made a bit of confusion here about JSONP response. More important: you have to change the `Content-type` to `application/javascript`, that may be the culprit

Comment: Setting this `contentType: 'application/javascript'` in remote validation nothing changes

Comment: can you post full request/response data using Fiddler?

Comment: Try to take a look... [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kGXsg/1/). Consider that the PHP page called from AJAX always returned a JSON formatted data with "true" or "false" (see the code at the beginning of this post)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little (too?) late, but it may help someone else...

The problem is that your "success" function overwrites the default one of the remote method; you must the errors yourself with

```
validator.showErrors();
```

from within your success function, provided that you saved the validator object (`var validator = $.validate({ ... })`).

Answer (score 0):

It has been quite long since this question is asked however no proper answer is yet given. I was having this same issue and had to spend more than few hours to get the answer. So, leave a complete answer here for anyone who may come across this.

You don't need the success function as its not executed so it should not be given. Instead you have to show the error in your callback function like one of the answer was given. Even though that indicates possible solution, it does not give clear example and tell you that success clause is not required.

Summary:

Success clause not required.
Your callback function should show errors.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {

    validator = $("#registerForm").validate({
        onkeyup: false,
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    type: 'get',
                    url: 'http://www.myurl.com/checkemail',
                    data: {
                        email: function() {
                            return $('#email').val();
                        }
                    },
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonp: 'myCallback'
                }
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            }


        }
    });
    myCallback = function(data) {
        console.log("myCallback data is :" + data);
        if (data !== "true")
            validator.showErrors({
                "email": "This email is already used"
            });
    };
});
```